# Bash script plug-in for Visual studio 2010/3?

Tags: linux, bash, visual-studio-2010, plugins, ksh

Are there any decent bash plug-ins for Visual studio?

I've googled to find a plug-in for bash or maybe ksh , 
but did not see anything that looked like bash/ksh plug-in.

- Meanwhile I used the notepad ++, but I want to find more professional editor like the **Microsoft visual studio**

Comment: What is your OS, Windows or Linux? I see `linux` tag, but Visual Studio does not run on Linux. Also, let's suppose that there is a "bash script plugin" for VS. What would be its purpose? Why do you need it?

Comment: I work on Linux ENV , I need it because working on VS shuld be better writing then notepadd++ , and maybe the bash plug-in is exsist will mark wrong syntax as for example for pytthon

Comment: Do you want syntax highlighting to spot errors in python?  http://pygments.org/  is one of many places to go for open source programs that do this.

Comment: I've got syntax highlighting on VS2015, but that's it: not code folding, no "go to definition", definitely no error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Tried https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a6932e93-c163-45d6-9992-2fca1b1fe4fd?

Although I think the bash part has only been added for 2013 version